# error 1281 for the call to glUseProgram

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

After hours of trouble shooting I think I've narrowed the problem to my fragment and vertex shader. I got a error 1281 for the glUseProgram call. And Ive checked to make sure they are no other errors before this call. Im trying to make a sphere, so it might be useful to know that some of the vertex coordinates have an 'E' in them, which means that sometimes they are eally small. Here are my fragment and vertex shaders.

```
final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;" +       // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.
                    "uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;" +        // A constant representing the combined model/view matrix.
                    "attribute vec4 a_Position;" +      // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
                    "attribute vec3 a_Normal;" +        // Per-vertex normal information we will pass in.
                    "varying vec3 v_Position;" +        // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
                    "varying vec3 v_Normal;" +          // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

                    "void main() {" +
                    "v_Position = vec3( u_MVMatrix * a_Position);" + // Transform the vertex into eye space.
                    "v_Normal = vec3( u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0));" + // Transform the normal's orientation into eye space.
                    // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
                    // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in normalized screen coordinates.
                    "gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;" +
                    "}";

    final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +// Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a precision in the fragment shader.
                    "uniform vec3 u_LightPos;" +        // The position of the light in eye space.
                    "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +    // The input texture.
                    "uniform vec4 v_Color;" +
                    "varying vec3 v_Position;" +        // Interpolated position for this fragment.
                    "varying vec3 v_Normal;" +          // Interpolated normal for this fragment.

                    "void main(){" +
                    "float distance = length(u_LightPos - v_Position);" + // Will be used for attenuation.
                    "vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - v_Position);" + // Get a lighting direction vector from the light to the vertex.
                    // Calculate the dot product of the light vector and vertex normal. If the normal and light vector are
                    // pointing in the same direction then it will get max illumination.
                    "float diffuse = max(dot(v_Normal, lightVector), 0.0);" +
                    "diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.25 * distance)));" +// Add attenuation.
                    "diffuse = diffuse + 0.7;" +// Add ambient lighting
                    "gl_FragColor = v_Color + diffuse;" +
                    "}";
```

here is my draw method

```
public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix, float[] mvMatrix, float[] mMatrix) {
        // Translate the cube into the screen.
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mvpMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mvpMatrix, 0, posX, posY, posZ);
        Matrix.scaleM(mvpMatrix, 0, scale, scale, scale);

        Matrix.rotateM(mvpMatrix, 0, rotX, 1, 0, 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(mvpMatrix, 0, rotY, 0, 1, 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(mvpMatrix, 0, rotZ, 0, 0, 1);

        // Logging errors before the call to glUseProgram
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.i("error", String.valueOf(error));
        }

        Log.i("mprogram", String.valueOf(GLES20.glIsProgram(mProgramHandle))); // true
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);

        int error1;
        while ((error1 = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            throw new RuntimeException("glUseProgram" + ": glError " + error1);
        }

        GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW); // Counter-clockwise winding.
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);// Enable face culling.
        GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);// What faces to remove with the face culling.

        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position");

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex coordinates to use when rendering.
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Normal");

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);

        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "v_Color");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVMatrix");

        // Pass in the model view matrix.
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvMatrix, 0);

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");

        // Pass in the modal view projection matrix.
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

        //Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
```

Edit

```
     int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
            int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

            mProgramHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();// create empty OpenGL ES PROGRAM
            GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgramHandle, vertexShader);  // add the vertex shader to program
            GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgramHandle, fragmentShader);// add the fragment shader to program
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgramHandle);// creates OpenGL ES PROGRAM executables
 check1();


        vertexCount = vertices.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
        vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
    }

    int check1() {
         int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetProgramiv(mProgramHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
    if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Could not link program: ");
        Log.e("TAG", GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(mProgramHandle));
        GLES20.glDeleteProgram(mProgramHandle);
        mProgramHandle = 0;
    }
    }
```

Edit 2

```
  public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }
```

Edit 3 Logcat

```
06-09 12:25:39.436  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.436  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.436   848:  859 V/WindowManager ]
    Window{430341b0 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
06-09 12:25:39.446  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.446  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.456  1164: 1164 D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar ]
    animateCollapsePanels
06-09 12:25:39.476  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.476  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.486 14020:15026 E/TAG      ]
    Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.486  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.496 14020:15026 E/TAG      ]
    Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.496  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.496   848:  848 V/WindowManager ]
    Window{430341b0 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
06-09 12:25:39.526  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.526  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.556   285:  285 I/SurfaceFlinger ]
    id=3619 Removed NainActivit (2/7)
06-09 12:25:39.566  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.566  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.566 14020:15026 E/TAG      ]
    Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.566  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.576 15014:15014 I/dalvikvm ]
    Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled, referenced from method com.google.apps.dots.android.newsstand.NSDepend.setupInternal
06-09 12:25:39.606  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.606  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.616 14020:15026 E/TAG      ]
    Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.616  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.636 14020:15026 E/TAG      ]
    Could not link program:
06-09 12:25:39.636  14020-15026/com.example.james.rollingsphere E/TAG﹕ [ 06-09 12:25:39.636 15014:15014 I/dalvikvm ]
    Could not find method android.os.PowerManager.isInteractive, referenced from method com.google.apps.dots.android.newsstand.util.AndroidUtil.isDeviceInteractive
```

Comment: Does the program compile and link successfully?

Comment: @Alex T. it compiles fine, and when debugging there are no errors in the log cat.

Comment: 1281 == GL_INVALID_VALUE. The only reason for this, is if the program is not valid

Comment: Post the code where you initialize the program

Comment: @MuertoExcobito i know what it means from research but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: @toom - show your shader initialization code. That's likely where the error is.

Comment: Are you sure you're checking that the link succeeded properly (not shown in your code)? Note that glLinkProgram will not return a GL error if it fails, you must call glGetProgramiv with GL_LINK_STATUS.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito please see update. Ive done the check and the logcat prints "I/mprogram﹕ false". its generated from the draw() method.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do with `check1` - you don't actually check the return value... if linking fails, you should call glGetProgramInfoLog, to find out what went wrong (and perhaps print that to the log).

Comment: @MuertoExcobito ive printed out the logcat. But it still just states the same problem that it couldn't link the program.

Comment: @toom Some drivers give more information, some less. Yours apparently gives none. I'd check https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLinkProgram.xml for the reasons linking can fail, and try to figure out which one. I'd guess that your shaders are not compiling, because you're not checking that they compile either.